# yii2 ActiveColumn in GridView. Where to pass model?

Tags: yii, yii2

I am creating an action on pressing view button. This is the URL which I am creating

```
return Url::to(['site/usermessages?id='.$model->ID]);
```

The problem which I am facing is that I am not able to understand where to return current model to this generated site,
could anyone give me advice?

```
     'buttons' => [
                //view button
                'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-search"></span>View', $url, [
                        'title' => Yii::t('app', 'View'),
                        'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs',

                    ]);
                },
            ],

            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                if ($action ==='view') {
                    return Url::to(['site/usermessages?id='.$model->ID]);
                }
            }
```

I'd like to simply display text in the new rendered site. for example, in `site/usermessages?id=2` I'd like to `echo $model->text` but as I said before I didn't get where to pass a model there.
Thank you for help.

Comment: you are hardcoding your urls. you should generate urls as follows: `Url::to(['site/usermessages', 'id'=>$model->id])`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want to disable the default view and delete buttons (because you have missleading code in your example)

but with template you can set the buttons which should be available (removed {view} {delte} etc.)
and i also give you en example if the "controller" should be different for one action. e.g. for usermessages the controller "site" is used and for the other button actions (if they won't be removed) the current controller will be used.

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'header'=>Yii::t('app', 'Actions'),
    'template' => '{usermessages}',
    'buttons' => [
        'usermessages' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-search"></span>View', $url, [
                'title' => Yii::t('app', 'View'),
                'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs',
            ]);
        },
    ],
    'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
        if ($action ==='usermessages') {
            return Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['site/'.$action, 'id' => $key]);
        } else {
            return Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl([$action, 'id'=>$key]);
        }
    },
],
```

your controller code

```
public function actionUsermessages($id)
{
    return $this->render('usermessages', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: any idea why there is a ,,Calling unknown method: app\controllers\SiteController::createUrl()'' error?

Comment: fixed it, was my mistake i had a function in my extended base controller.

Comment: okey it works but still i think you didnt understund my question or I just simply didnt specify it enough. Now code generates url exacly as it did before. And problem i dont understund is: For example i am pressing at row 2 i wanted to display new site that shows this all row2 info. Okey it generates url with my site, it calls controller which is  public function actionUsermessages(){
        return $this->render('usermessages');
    }. Before i was making object ($model) in controller and i was passing it with return. Now i wanted to pass $model from this row2 to new-displayed site.

Comment: what you want is to render something in the actionUsermessages?

Comment: I was about to create something like post, you can see the begining of text in the gridView columns (which is in messages.php) but when you press view it moves you to the new site and display not only begining but whole conversation. I just simply do not know how to move current pressed $model to new site (usermessages.php) so i could get all info there.

Comment: What you want is to create a so called crud controller. Which hase this functionallity:  
    Listing all records,  
    Showing one given record identified by its primary key,  
    Creating a new record,  
    Editing an existing record,  
    Deleting an existing record.  

[guide-tool-gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tool-gii.html)  
[Creating a Simple CRUD App With Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/490/creating-a-simple-crud-app-with-yii2-revised-12-20-2013/)